# Regex help: data after last slash and before interrogation and after interrogation

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have the following url´s types in my application:

```
http://192.168.0.191/myapp/public/controller_name/action_name
http://192.168.0.191/myapp/public/controller_name/action_name/param1/param2
http://192.168.0.191/myapp/public/controller_name/action_name?parameterlist
```

Ans I´m using the following REGEX for redirection:

I have the following Regex for redirection (everything goes through the index page):

`"^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$"` redirects to `"/myapp/public/index.php?url=$1&extension=$2")`

Here are examples of URLs used:

```
http://192.168.0.191/myapp/public/customers -> Call customer controller
http://192.168.0.191/myapp/public/customers/detail/2 -> Show customer detail for id = 2
```

Both works fine. My problem is with the URL below - to load customer data for a Datagrid object:

```
http://192.168.0.191/myapp/public/customer/loadDtData?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=desc&start=0&length=25&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1450111563514
```

How can I fix the Regex to separate the text after the last `/` but before the `?` and then text after the `?` to pass as parameter to the application.

Thanks for helping. I´m using lighttpd as web server.

OBS: For Apache I would use the `RewriteRule` below to make the trick, but lighttpd does not have support for QSA:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?url=$1&extension=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of `QSA` flag try this rule:

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/([\w/-]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?(?:\?(.*))?" => "/index.php?url=$1&extension=$2&$3" )
```

[Reference](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/MigratingFromApache)

Comment: It seens that this syntax does not work with lighttpd... At least the [L] flag doesn´t

Comment: Now it´s downloading the file index instead of loading it.... I added `static-file.exclude-extensions = { ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" }` and now I´m getting `4003 - Forbidden`.